# Monoidalness of a model category can be checked on generators

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

If $C$ is a cofibrantly generated model category which is also monoidal biclosed, then to check that $C$ is a monoidal model category, it suffices to check that the Leibniz product of generating cofibrations is a cofibration, that the Leibniz product of a generating cofibration with a generating acyclic cofibration is an acyclic cofibration, and that the unit axiom is satisfied.

The proof is a little involved, so I'd like to have a source to cite this from. Where can I find it in the literature?

I'm happy to assume that the unit is cofibrant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Corollary 4.2.5 of Hovey's book. The proof is not that involved.

Comment: I see. It's cleaner to check lifting properties directly, rather than checking closure under cobase change, transfinite composition, and retract. Thanks!

Comment: Not only cleaner, but it doesn't require any smallness property on the classes of "generating" (acyclic) cofibrations or the objects involved.